# Integral from $N(x)$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, statistics

I need closed form for next integral:

$$I = \int_a^{\infty}\phi(x)\Phi(\alpha x+\beta) dx,$$
where $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ are PDF and CDF of standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you want to compute in a closed form
$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}\int_a^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \,\,\text{erfc}\left(-\frac{\alpha  x+\beta }{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dx$$

Having made, in the past, an extensive search on the Internet of *"integrals involving the error function"* I did not find anything for $a\neq 0$.

In my humble opinion, beside numerical integration, approximations or series, there is a very little hope that you get a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much